# Что общего между Huawei и D-link

Tags: d-link

Кто сможет прояснить ситуацию. В прошивке D-link'a (в одной из функций) нашёл упоминание о Huawei (функция генерации донгла). Был немного ошарашен....какое отношение друг к другу имеют эти две корпорации. А погуглив, я нашёл вот это [image: вырезка с pdf]
Данные компании объединились что-ли?

Comment: "функция генерации донгла"? Программа, генерирующая аппаратуру? Или что вы понимаете под "донглом"?

Comment: Ключ. Это электронный ключ. Для 3g сетей.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что программисты не занимаются аппаратными проблемами.

Comment: Вопрос общего толка, к программированию имеет косвенное отношение. К тому же ответ получен и вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не список "электронных ключей". Это список совместимых с вашим роутером USB 3g-модемов. "Совместимых" означает "проверенных производителем роутера".

Если вы купите любой из списка и воткнете в роутер - он заработает. Если как-то другой - никаких гарантий.

Ваш производитель роутера (D-Link) проверил совместимость с некоторыми модемами от D-Link и с некоторыми модемами от Huawei. Никакого заговора.

Comment: А уже подумал... Теперь значимость данной функции прояснилась. Спасибо.